# Tag synonym/rename/merge requests

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

**If you have a request to create tag synonyms, or rename or merge tags,** post the request here as answers.  Site adminstrators can then act on the request.

Requests are for tags on [the Science Fiction & Fantasy SE main site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) by default.  If your request is about tags on [meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/), please indicate that specifically.

Admins: please edit the answer to indicate that the request is completed or declined.

Comment: See also: [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710/271002)

Comment: I don't think a single question for tag action requests is a good idea. First, it doesn't allow for as convenient discussion on the idea, and second, the mods (and the rest of the community) are not going to monitor this thread for new suggestions, but we get notifications of new meta posts.

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed): synonymisation [is complete](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/winterbash/synonyms).

---

On Sci Fi meta, can please you rename [[hats]](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hats) to [winterbash] so it has the same name as [[winterbash]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winterbash) on Meta SE and so it's easier to find?  Leave [hats] as a synonym.

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed): synonymisation [is complete](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/werewolf/synonyms).

---

Make [lycanthropy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lycanthropy) a synonym of [werewolf](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/werewolf).

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed): Keen/user1027 [did this synonymisation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/star-wars-finn/synonyms) in January.

---

Per [this deleted question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7855/1027):

Make [fn-2187](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fn-2187) a synonym of [star-wars-finn](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-finn).

Answer (score 0):

Make [apparition](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apparition) (which doesn't refer to ghosts but to the magical transportation used in the Harry Potter universe) a synonym of [magical-transportation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magical-transportation).

Comment: [tag:teleportation] is also relevant, see. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/51777/4918

Comment: Teleportation is often a sci-fi technology, and shouldn't be a synonym for a magic-exclusive transportation.

Comment: @amaranth Probably better to propose them as separate questions actually, unless they're no-brainers like [tag:lineage] and [tag:genealogy]. If it needs discussing, a new question will get more attention and votes than yet another answer on this old one.

Answer (score 0):

Make [genre-trope](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genre-trope) a synonym of [trope](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trope).

The former only has 3 questions, and we really only deal with a small (some would say < 3) genres here, so it should be self-evidence that our trope questions about sci-fi or fantasy tropes.