# Do we need a "credits" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Do we need a tag for what happens on-screen during [credits](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/credits) (end titles of a movie)?

I think this would be useful because [searching on "credits"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=credits) gives you:

- credits (end titles of a movie)
- credit (singular, as in "give credit to") and
- credits (currency in multiple sci-fi stories)

Comment: According to the [tag scoring criteria here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7871/tag-wars-episode-i-harry-potter-and-the-tag-cleanup), the proposed [tag:credits] tag would have a score of at most 4 (4 only if there are >15 questions qualifying for the tag, which I doubt). *[Summary: -1,-1,2,1,?,-1,1,-1,2.]* This suggests that **no**, it wouldn't be a useful tag.

Comment: @randal'thor. Thanks, great link. I score it differently: -1,-1,2,1,2,1,1,-1,2 =  6. Which is still not enough. :)

Comment: @randal'thor- yes, good idea. It's a very useful link - maybe even add to the [FAQ].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### No.

[This post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7871/tag-wars-episode-i-harry-potter-and-the-tag-cleanup) has a tag scoring sheet, copied over from another site, to determine what makes a good tag. Let's see how [credits](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/credits) scores:

1. *Does it make sense to be an "expert* in [credits](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/credits)"?*
   **No**; score **-1**.
2. Does it make sense for a question to be tagged *only* with [credits](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/credits)"?
   **No** (there should also be a tag for the film or franchise in question); score **-1**.
3. Does [credits](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/credits) have a single, universally-unambiguous meaning?
   **Yes** (as you defined in your question); score **2**.
4. Is [credits](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/credits) likely to be used correctly just based on its name?
   **Maybe** (although there are other meanings of the word, as mentioned in your question); score **1**.
5. Are there "enough" (> 15) but not "too many" (> 10% site-wide) questions that qualify for [credits](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/credits)?
   **Maybe?** Someone would have to count them to check, so for the moment I'll say score **1**.
6. Are people like to use [credits](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/credits) to find questions to answer?
   **Maybe?** I'd say probably not, but let's say score **1**.
7. Are there likely some users (*be objective!*) who will favorite or ignore [credits](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/credits)?
   **Maybe?** The fact that you've asked this question shows a certain level of interest! Score **1**.
8. Could [credits](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/credits) be reasonably used to feed questions to a specialized chat room?
   **No**; score **-1**.
9. Can [credits](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/credits) be used to search for questions (for any reason) in a way that keyword searching cannot accomplish?
   **Yes** (because as you said, the word has more than one meaning); score **2**.

Total is **5**, which is apparently not enough for the tag to be worth creating. From the linked question:

> tags that score > 12 are "good" tags, tags that score < 8 are "terrible" tags, others are likely good but may need some clarification/renaming/etc

Comment: Regarding point 5; I made a mistake in [my calculation](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8123/do-we-need-a-credits-tag/8125#comment23141_8123). Maybe of those links had references to the credits in *answers*. Only a much smaller number had *questions about the credits* (three on the first page of questions).

Comment: @Wikis So is that definitely a -1 then?

Comment: I only checked the first page (3 items) but there were 16 pages. So it probably would reach above "15" but less than the hundred or so I initially thought.

Comment: @Wikis OK, so I'll leave it at "maybe".

Comment: Indeed, if it was borderline I would research it but the score is not close enough.

Comment: #3 would be a no, actually. The OP's post showed that there's at least 3 meanings, which says that it's an ambiguous term. However, `ending-credits` is not ambiguous (that I can tell).

Comment: @CreationEdge The *word* is ambiguous, but the *tag* wouldn't be. So yes to #3 and no/maybe to #4.

Comment: Ah, that's not how I interpreted the question.