# Should we have a tolkien-language tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

A quick search of `tolkien language` yields [161 results](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=tolkien+language), 33 of them [questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=tolkien+language+is%3Aquestion), while `quenya` yields [89 results](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=quenya).  I scored [tolkien-language](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien-language) using [this system](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7871/51142) and got 12 (+2, -1, +1, +2, +2, +2, +1, +2, +1), which is pretty darn good, and according to the aforementioned post is good enough to be a tag.  There is even a [klingon-language](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/klingon-language) tag, which seems preposterous since I think [tolkien-language](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien-language) would be much better.

Comment: I added some links to search results, and fixed the markup (cc @amaretto)

Comment: Perhaps, but it should of course be tolkien-language***s***

Comment: @curiousdannii Of course

Comment: @curiousdannii As I always say, i amba, i lil mará!

Comment: Would a question on Tolkein’s languages be tagged [tag:tolkein-languages], [tag:tolkein], [tag:languages]? It seems like the [tag:klingon-language] questions should add [tag:languages] too, so that people following [tag:languages] don’t have to follow every specific language tag.

Comment: Another obvious case for the tag: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/121951/what-language-did-hobbits-speak-before-men

Comment: So if there's no answer should I just make the tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very good question, @CHEESE; funnily enough, I was about to ask the same exact question when you ninja'd me!  Anyway, I certainly agree with everything you have said; [tolkien-languages](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien-languages) makes perfect sense given how well it did on [this system](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7871/51142) and all of those searches, and given that ***nobody has yet responded and tried to negate your efforts***, @CHEESE, this seems like a great idea and should be created ASAP.

Comment: I hate being self-ninja'd. So embarrassing.

Comment: What do you think about adding [tag:languages] while you're at it?

Comment: @amarillo To what?

Comment: To the questions you're retagging. If they have to do with [tag:tolkien-languages], then they're also related to [tag:languages].

Comment: @amarillo OK, I can

Comment: @CHEESE But please don't swamp the front page with tag edits. A rough rule of thumb to prevent the swamping out of new questions is to ensure that **no more than 5 of the top 15** posts on the front page were last edited by you.

Comment: @randal'thor Good to know.  Only one of the questions I tagged [tolkien-languages] didn't have [languages]