# Are tags with multiple meanings confusing? / Should 'Metropolis' tag be changed to include classic SciFi film?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

The current [metropolis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metropolis) tag description seems lacking in that it is limited to questions about the place where Superman lives.

However the word 'Metropolis' to me, particularly in a SciFi/Fantasy context, conjures thoughts and images of this film classic.

[image] [image] [image] [image]

Should the [Fritz Lang movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis_(1927_film)) be added to the tag wiki, or is that just confusing?

Here is an example of a tag that has been assigned multiple uses: [2012](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2012)

Comment: @armadillo I was actually surprised that there _was_ a question about Superman's city, and that there _wasn't_ one about the film ;) I don't think we need one about the city either, but maybe Marvel superfans feel otherwise.

Comment: Maybe it should be scheduled as a potential question-theme-for-the-week or something... Get everyone reeducated on their roots ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Null's excellent answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9751/31394) covers the general principles - most importantly, **tags with multiple meanings should be avoided if possible**.

I'm just posting this second answer to say I've now sorted out the specific tags you were asking about.

- [metropolis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metropolis)

  Several [people](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9750/are-tags-with-multiple-meanings-confusing-should-metropolis-tag-be-changed#comment27157_9750) have [expressed](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9750/are-tags-with-multiple-meanings-confusing-should-metropolis-tag-be-changed#comment27164_9750) the [opinion](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9751/31394) here that a special tag for the *Superman* city of Metropolis is unnecessary. Plus I searched for [questions containing the word Metropolis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=metropolis+is%3Aquestion) and discovered that the tag wasn't even being used consistently: there are several questions that *could* be tagged [metropolis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metropolis), but only [one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95071/how-much-of-metropolis-is-toronto) that actually was. So I nuked this tag.

  For the 1927 film, I created a new tag [metropolis-1927](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metropolis-1927) and posted [the first question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/129992/where-is-metropolis) about this film. I also created a tag wiki for this new tag, just to avoid any possible confusion.

  If anyone posts a question about the 2001 film, that should be tagged [metropolis-2001](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metropolis-2001).
- [2012](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2012)

  The tag wiki excerpt for this tag previously read:

  > Questions pertaining to either the 2009 movie called "2012", or to any SFF works referencing the year of 2012 A.D.

  The second half of this is just ridiculous. We really don't need a tag for all SFF works referencing a particular year; similarly, we [already got rid of](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7871/tag-wars-episode-i-harry-potter-and-the-tag-cleanup/7872#7872) the decade tags [70s](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/70s), [80s](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/80s), [90s](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/90s). I've edited the tag wiki accordingly. Possibly the tag name should also be edited to e.g. [2012-film](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2012-film), but I'm not sure about that one, so I left it for the time being.

Answer (score 5):

### Tags with multiple meanings should be avoided if possible.

Tags assist with searching, and a user searching for information about the city where Superman lives probably doesn't care about questions/answers discussing the film (or vice versa). Users who post high scoring answers also earn tag badges as a way to demonstrate expertise, but a user who is an expert in the *Metropolis* film isn't necessarily an expert regarding the city where Superman lives.

The typical way around this is to use separate tags with related names. For example, we have [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek) for the franchise but [star-trek-2009](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-2009) for the film within that franchise from the year 2009.

There currently aren't any questions about *Metropolis* the film, but if we ever did get a question about it I would suggest creating a tag named [metropolis-1927-film](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metropolis-1927-film) or [metropolis-1927](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metropolis-1927) (which also distinguishes it from the [2001 film of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis_%282001_film%29)). The tag wikis for that new tag and [metropolis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metropolis) should refer to each other and explain when one is appropriate and the other is not. (Actually, I doubt we really need a [metropolis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metropolis) for the Superman city anyway.)

[2012](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2012) is a poor tag name. It would be better if it were renamed [2012-film](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2012-film) or similar to reflect the movie. We don't need a tag for SFF works referencing the year 2012 anyway.

Comment: @armadillo Conventions aside, I think metropolis-film is clearer. Nonetheless, I've added your suggestion. The name is debatable, but it should not be simply "metropolis" and it should not be used for the city in the Superman franchise at the same time.

Comment: @armadillo Ah, I wasn't aware of that film. Thanks for letting me know. I've updated my suggestions.

Comment: @armadillo - Luckily, the odds of someone remaking 2012 are about the same as someone remaking Star Crash.